# Button and label not showing in Interface Builder and the simulator even if they are not marked as "hidden"

Tags: ios, uiview

I have just started learning ios and I was making a button tap counter app, where an user can tap the button for a entered number of times. The problem that I came across is mentioned in the title. Please see attached screenshot image for clarification. Notice in the screenshot that the app logo isn't shown when "Hidden" is unchecked. When "Hidden" is checked, the logo isn't shown, but its fine because that is just how it is (just mentioning). This is the case for all other buttons, images, labels and text fields.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a Z axis issue.
Meaning, a UIView is on top of your UIButton.

You will need to drag the UI elements downwards in order to change the Z axis hierarchy:

[image]

Also, you could figure this issue by yourself if you would use the Debug View Hierarchy:

[image]